# Freezing mask without breakpoint

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a strange issue on a program that I'm writing.
The language is C#, I'm using Win 10 x64, Visual Studio Community 2019, and the software is client/server (Sql Server Express, installed on the same machine), single thread.

The problem happens in a windows form, when selecting an icon to be displayed.
If I place a breakpoint at the start of the subroutine which manages the icon everything works fine, but when I try to remove it (the breakpoint) the entire form freezes and I can't click anywhere, moreover pushing F5 doesn't change anything and I have to stop the execution to get back to my code.

Even If I pause the execution the call stack results empty.
What do you think can cause such a behaviour?

Comment: My first guess is something floods the ui-thread with tasks. Is one cpu-core on 100%?

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you very much.
I felt the need to answer because trying to show the cpu usage resulted in a change.
The Cpu usage is always very low (less than 10% at worst), but following the instructions on Microsoft Docs I put the execution (while in Cpu usage testing) in Release, as opposed to before when removing the breakpoint I left the execution in Debug, and everything runs fine.
So now the question changes:
why do it's alright in Release mode and freeze when in Debug mode but without the breakpoint?
They are the same, aren't they?
Thank you very much again.

Comment: Hi Alex, if your question has changed, please do not answer it with another question, just edit the original question to make it more specific. Also, I'm not sure this is a great question because it is not very specific so please try and ask a very specific question.

Comment: If you are running in debug mode, you may have specified a `conditional break-point`, which drastically reduces the execution speed of the application.  Use `Debug > Windows > Breakpoints` or `Debug > Delete All Breakpoints`.